# How to shut up Visual Studio's "There is no source code available for the current location."?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Is there a way to disable the popup without forcing myself to see the disassembly?

The popup is very intrusive and especially annoying when I'm trying to analyze stack traces quickly. :(

Comment: +1 I don't think you adequately expressed (how) annoying it is!

Comment: Popup? I just get that 'blank' screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least on [Visual Studio 2013](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2013) the other answer given here didn't work for me. I've found the extension http://disablenosourcetab.codeplex.com/. It disables the tab completely for me.